# how to read multiple paper set in raphael js

Tags: svg, raphael

i have bunch of images on my canvas which i am rotating, scaling with the help of raphael js and raphael-free-transform plugin

i have this issue. i need border around image object,since svg doesn't allow stroke around image i added a rect by setting stroke of the rect. combined the image and rect in a paper.set() and apply free transform on the set itself.
code is

```
img = paper.image(image.src, tx, ty, 362, 500); //main image
            rec = paper.rect(tx, ty, 362, 500).attr({'stroke':'#ff00ff','stroke-width':'2'});
            var se = $paper.set();
            se.push(img);
            se.push(rec);
            ft = paper.freeTransform(se)
```

now all works fine, but i need to replicate the paper elements as it is, on another canvas also, i used raphael.serialize to copy elements from paper to another paper. only problem is copying the transformation applied to the elemens.

earlier without the border  every node use to have property called 'freeTransform'(added by raphael-free-transform.js') which i use to copy at replicate on another paper.

but since now i am applying my free transform on the **set()** i don't get this property value.

Hope my question is clear. any pointers to solution will be greatly appreciated. :)